# See all process run sorted by start time

Tags: linux, ps

If I run this on my terminal:

```
ps -ef --sort=start_time
```

then I receive back a list of the processes sorted by their start time **which are still running**.

What is the command to receive back a list of the processes sorted by their start time **but *not only* the ones which are still running but also the ones which may have been completed or killed in the meantime**?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? Maybe tell us *why* you want to list those? `ps` clearly says: _displays information about a selection of the **active** processes_

Comment: @0stone0, to see what run for example the last hours on my server?
(I think it is obvious)

Comment: The processes that has been completed won't show up in `ps`. This idea has already been answered here: [How to view processes executed in the last *](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61462/how-to-view-commandline-of-processes-executed-in-last-10-seconds)